# Sql injection from form

Tags: php, sql-injection, user-registration

I test my site with Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner 8 and its say that i have 2 sql injection in my register page

URL encoded POST input email was set to 1##xa7##
URL encoded POST input username was set to 1##xa7##

Error message found: supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result

Php code for these two

```
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));

        if ($username==!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$/', $username)){
         $error_stat = 1; 
              $message_error .= 'Error:invalid username.';
        }
         elseif (!filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error_stat = 11; 
              $message_error .= 'Error:invalid email.';

          }
```

So how this can be vulnerable to sql injection

@Pekka

```
 $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username = '$username'");
    $checkemail = mysql_query("SELECT EmailAddress FROM users WHERE EmailAddress = '$email'");

    $username_exist = mysql_num_rows($checkusername);
    $email_exist = mysql_num_rows($checkemail);
```

And if one of them exist to show error:

```
<?php if ($error_stat > 0){ echo $message_error; }?>
```

If there is no errors

```
$registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Username, password, EmailAddress,Activation,registered) VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."','".$activation."','".$date."')");
```

EDIT //

So guys i make a another page with PDO and new error is:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (cp1251_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

This what the Acunetix show when i click on Launch the attack with HTTP Editor.And the username used by program is `1%c0%00xa7%c0a2`

PDO

By the program the username is = 1%c0%00xa7%c0a2 and error is in line 32

```
 line 30 $getMail = $dbh->prepare("SELECT EmailAddress FROM users WHERE username = :username");
    line 31 $getMail->bindParam(':username', $username);
    line 32 $getMail->execute();
    line 33 $rowMail = $getMail->fetch();
    line 34 $email = $rowMail['emailaddress'];
```

Comment: Can you show the database code you are using?

Comment: you need to post more code. I can't tell if you are looking at $error_stat after you set it.

Comment: (i) preg_match returns boolean so I do not get what `$username` is supposed to contain (ii) Can you post the code you use to build the query?

Comment: I and the check for existing acc and mail and code if there is no errors

Comment: ideally you should be using prepared statements.

Comment: Can you show the full code, including where you do the mysql_real_escape_string()?

Comment: as Salman A said, your first condition is always false, as `preg_match` will never return a string to match to your username. Since this is so, you probably don't check the `$error_stat` to see if the error has occurred http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: I'm not seeing how you are sanitizing your form inputs before using them in your sql queries, can you show that part?

Comment: this is still not the full code but some bits and pieces. One cannot even tell on which like the error occurred.

Comment: I change the code to PDO but still there is error

Answer (score -1):

From what I can tell you should escape all fields in here:

```
$registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Username, password, EmailAddress,Activation,registered) VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."','".$activation."','".$date."')");
```

You have:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));
```

You should have the same for $password, $activation and $date... Not sure if you do

Anyway I use normally use this:

```
function getPost($s) {
        if (array_key_exists($s, $_POST))
            return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST[$s]));
        else return false;
    }


    function getGet($s) {
        if (array_key_exists($s, $_GET))
            return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_GET[$s]));
        else return false;
    }
```

But it's to protect against XSS also... I though you should be safe with mysql_real_escape_string().

Anyway you can also use Prepared statements and forget all about this!! http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

**EDIT**
Well, no valid username there, right? So what about this:

```
try{
$getMail = $dbh->prepare("SELECT EmailAddress FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$getMail->bindParam(':username', $username);
$getMail->execute();
$rowMail = $getMail->fetch();
$email = $rowMail['emailaddress'];
}
catch( PDOException $Exception ) {
echo 'Authentication Failed';
}
```

Can't test it right now, but it should be something around this lines...

Comment: I do have ,but Acunetix show errors only for username and email thats why i show only them

Comment: your getPost/get functions are quite useless.

Comment: Don't question that but, can you please elaborate? I would like to learn :)

Comment: "The parameters to prepared statements don't need to be quoted; the driver automatically handles this. If an application exclusively uses prepared statements, the developer can be sure that no SQL injection will occur (however, if other portions of the query are being built up with unescaped input, SQL injection is still possible)."